# Getting Error non-negative integer value expected in LIMIT clause

Tags: java, sql, exasolution

I want to fetch data from exasol but only facing this issue when I use limit clause in query.

If i hardcode the limit values in query and don't use prepared statement for then it works fine. But when I try to set int for limit clause in prepared statement it gives me exception

```
public static final String FROM_DWB_DATA = "SELECT *  FROM DWB_DATA a \n"
    + "INNER JOIN DWB_CONN b \n"
    + "ON a.SOURCE_ID=b.ID\n"
    + "WHERE b.PROJECT_ID=? ORDER BY a.TABLE_NAME LIMIT ? , ?";


    //and in Prepared statement i am setting these values
    PreparedStatement ps = getSQLConnection(projectId, conid)
        .prepareStatement(FROM_DWB_DATA_TABLE);

    ps.setString(1, projectId);
    ps.setInt(2, 0);
    ps.setInt(3, 2);
```

> java.sql.SQLException: non-negative integer value expected in LIMIT clause

Comment: What are you expecting `LIMIT 0 , 2` to mean?

Comment: page number and page size,  Limit  (pageNum-1) * pageSize ,  pageSize

Comment: What flavour SQL are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, it adds your values in quoted form: `LIMIT '0', '2'`.

Try to build query string normally and run it as simple non-prepared query.